EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0800000000000000b EFI stub

I am using Ubuntu 24.04 on an Asus laptop. I have both Windows 11 and Ubuntu. When I boot to Ubuntu I am getting the following error message:
EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0800000000000000b EFI stub   
EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0800000000000000b EFI stub  

It will stay there for 5 minutes and then I can boot, enter and get Ubuntu.
Can someone please tell me what is the issue that's causing this error and how to fix it, so that my boot and load Ubuntu much faster within seconds like my Windows 11.

Had this happen on a new install of Mint 22 BETA. I then disabled Secure Boot and message did not come up

I had this error in Kubuntu due to a modified secure boot key in EFI.
What I did to fix the problem was:

Boot into your computer's BIOS settings.  (Repeatedly pressing the delete key during reboot is the most common way to get into the BIOS.)  In the BIOS go to the Security tab.

Enable Secure Boot.  Change Secure Boot from Standard to Custom.  This creates a new menu to configure Secure Boot.

In this new menu it lists Secure Boot keys. There should be a reset to defaults option.  Select it to reset your Secure Boot keys.

Leave the custom menu and turn Secure Boot back into Standard mode, then disable Secure Boot.  (Most, maybe all, Linux distros do not support Secure Boot.)


This fixed it for me.
